# DeepLinking in Flutter with FlutterFragmentActivity

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies, deep-linking, android-fragmentactivity

I have an Straming app that connects to ChromeCast.

It uses this package to handle the connection:
https://github.com/samyakkkk/flutter_video_cast

It needs to use FlutterFragmentActivity so the connection can work, but, if i use it, i lose the hability to DeepLinking. How can i succed in this if i need to use FlutterFragmentActivity?

Here is the code that makes Chromecast Work but breaks DeepLinking:

```
    class MainActivity : FlutterFragmentActivity() {

    override fun provideFlutterEngine(context: Context): FlutterEngine? {
        return AudioServicePlugin.getFlutterEngine(context)
    }
    
    override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine)
        provideFlutterEngine(applicationContext)
    }
}
```

Here is the code that DeepLinking works but breaks the ChromeCast connection:

```
    class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {
    override fun provideFlutterEngine(context: Context): FlutterEngine? {
        configureFlutterEngine(FlutterEngine(applicationContext))
        return AudioServicePlugin.getFlutterEngine(context)
    }
}
```

I need to use "AudioServicePlugin" for playing audio, so this line need to be set also.

Comment: What exactly are you doing with your deep-linking? Maybe there's another way to do it?

Comment: Hi @Dave, i use it for the users to open the website urls using the app and for sharing links in general.

Comment: If you can describe in order the steps the user takes in your question, I reckon we can work out another to do what you want.

Comment: The deeplinking in my app is used when a user open a link from our associated website, and the link defines the route that the app should use.
Using the flutter_video_cast package the deeplinking only works when the app is in hot state ( running in backgroud ), if it is in cold state (completely closed) it dosent work, only if i switch back to FlutterActivity instead of FlutterFragmentActivity.

Comment: "Deep links are a type of link that send users directly to an app instead of a website or a store. They are used to send users straight to specific in-app locations, saving users the time and energy locating a particular page themselves – significantly improving the user experience."